# Bash script do not return value

Tags: bash, shell

I have a problem with the return of a value during a script call.

This is a routine that includes the call of different scripts.
This routine is launched from rc.local

*rc.local*

```
...
/bin/bash /toto.sh
...
```

*toto.sh*

```
#!/bin/bash

. livebox.sh
. network.sh
. dns.sh

EXTERNALIP=0
LOGFILE=/var/log/dns.log

echo "$(date '+%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S') : Start running routine" >> $LOGFILE

while true
do

    while true
    do
        is_ok=($(is_network_ok)) # <<<<<< HERE IS THE PROBLEM
        echo "$(date '+%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S') : is network ok? > $is_ok" >> $LOGFILE

        if [ $is_ok ]
        then
            IPWAN=$(echo $EXTERNALIP)
            IP=$(get_livebox_ip)
            if [ $IPWAN != $IP ]
                echo "$(date '+%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S') : IPWAN has changed" >> $LOGFILE
                then
                export EXTERNALIP=$IP
                # update du dns
                update_dns
                echo "$(date '+%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S') : New IPWAN is $IP" >> $LOGFILE
                break
            else
                break
            fi
        else
            echo "$(date '+%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S') : Network is down, round for 5 mins" >> $LOGFILE
            sleep 5m
        fi
    done
    sleep 1h
done
```

*network.sh*

```
#!/bin/bash

is_network_ok() {
        fssid=$(iwgetid -r)
        ssid="HAHAHAHAHAHA"
        if [ $fssid != $ssid ]
                then
                        echo false
                else
                        echo true
        fi
}
```

And that is the result

*dns.log*

```
2021-11-01 01:42:21 : Start running routine
2021-11-01 01:42:22 : is network ok? > 
2021-11-01 01:42:22 : Network is down, round for 5 mins
2021-11-01 01:44:07 : Start running routine
2021-11-01 01:44:07 : is network ok? > true
```

The 3rd lines come from the launch from rc.local
The last two from manual launch ( ./toto.sh)

Why i have no result from the rc.local ??
And why its work when i run it manualy ??

thx a lot

Comment: An infinite loop inside another infinite loop?  And there is no code inside the first while loop, so it is not required, right?  When you say you have no result from rc.local, you mean that there is nothing written to the log file?

Comment: Ah, after fixing the code (commented out the <<<<), I see the `sleep 1h` in the original loop.  You could trigger it once an hour via crontab and avoid rc.local completly.  Check your code via https://www.shellcheck.net/, it will not fix the question, but will cleanup a couple details.

Comment: Please paste your script at [shellcheck.net](http://www.shellcheck.net/) and try to implement the recommendations made there.

Comment: If you want to isolate the failure point so you can ask a question that's narrow and specific enough to be on topic, `set -x` is your friend, especially if you set a `PS4` that includes file name and line number with each traced command.

Comment: Additionally, you need to check if `rc.local` is run after the network is setup and available. Many times there are other hooks provided for inittab like `rc.after_network` for processes that need a network up before being launched. At least that makes sense why manual works and when called at startup it fails.

Comment: _ return of a value_  Define what you mean be "return value" of a script. Exit code? Text on stdout? On stderr? Or both? Or either?

Comment: yes, it is very likely that in the future it will end up in the crontab

Yes, the network is up, because even though the routine is running, if I raise it by hand, the network appears. Even if it is not accessible, the next round must do its job

I can debug with set -x only in "manual" mode? because if I run by hand, there is no problem.
It's at launch via rc.local

When I say a value return referring to the "echo" of the network script which returns true or false in toto.sh

Comment: @Nic3500 so any idea why it work when launch manually ?

Comment: I started looking into it, but I noticed that the echo for `IPWAN has changed` is before the `then` of the preceding `if` statement.  Go through shellcheck.net, fix the syntax, post revised code in your question.

Comment: For your line `is_ok=($(is_network_ok))`, no need for the second set of parentheses.  `is_ok=$(is_network_ok)` is enough.  It works on my laptop, manually.  Fix the syntax issues first, try again.  Note that if you test your script with bash, rc.local will run it with sh since that is what you have in your `#!` line.  You might want to change it to bash.  Other than that, log like crazy (-x option in your `#!`) to see what the rc.local does differently than when you run it manually.  Remember that the environment will be different then your user's.

Comment: Also the `. livebox.sh`, since you do not specify a path, I wonder if rc.local does not find these, since it most probably does not run the script from the same directory you are manually.  You might have to specify full paths.